# Should arrays be used in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, conventions

Since `std::list` and `std::vector` exist, is there a reason to use traditional C arrays in C++, or should they be avoided, just like `malloc`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between std::array and std::vector? When do you use one over other?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632971/what-is-the-difference-between-stdarray-and-stdvector-when-do-you-use-one-o)

Comment: @Als: That question concerns the difference between two specific containers, while this question concerns the difference between raw arrays and standard containers in general.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

In C++11 where [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is available, the answer is "yes, arrays should be avoided". Prior to C++11, you may need to use C arrays to allocate arrays in the automatic storage (i.e. on the stack).

Comment: many compilers do still lack C++11 support however. You will have to decide when it's better to use one rather than the other given the lack of std::array

Comment: std::array is a template, which impacts large projects in terms of build time and possibly code size since for each combination of T,N the template is instantiated anew.

Comment: std::vector guarantees data alignment by standard, so it can be used almost everywhere. With C++11 there really is no reason to use C arrays.

Comment: @Nils arrays guarantee alignment too. Plus, automatic storage allocation ("the stack") is way faster than dynamic storage allocation. If I *know* I have *exactly* 3 elements [e.g., coordinates of a triangle], there's no reason to use vector.

Comment: Ah yes, if it has to live on the stack, then you cannot use vector IIRC.

Comment: @zvrba - Check the generated assembly when using std::array vs C arrays. No difference at all.

Comment: While theoretically better in every way, in practice `std::array` is a headache to use.

Comment: There's also boost::array that can be used if std::array is not available.

Comment: But on the other hand, C array could be aligned through compile support, how can std::array<T> do it?

Answer (score 85):

Definitely, although with `std::array` in C++11, practically only for
static data.  C style arrays have three important advantages over
`std::vector`:

- They don't require dynamic allocation.  For this reason, C style
  arrays are to be preferred where you're likely to have a lot of very
  small arrays.  Say something like an n-dimension point:

  ```
  template <typename T, int dims>
  class Point
  {
      T myData[dims];
  // ...
  };
  ```

  Typically, one might imagine a that `dims` will be very small (2 or 3),
  `T` a built-in type (`double`), and that you might end up with
  `std::vector<Point>` with millions of elements.  You definitely don't
  want millions of dynamic allocations of 3 double.
- The support static initialization.  This is only an issue for static
  data, where something like:

  ```
  struct Data { int i; char const* s; };
  Data const ourData[] =
  {
      { 1, "one" },
      { 2, "two" },
      //  ...
  };
  ```

  This is often preferable to using a vector (and `std::string`), since it
  avoids *all* order of initialization issues; the data is pre-loaded,
  before any actual code can be executed.
- Finally, related to the above, the compiler can calculate the actual
  size of the array from the initializers.  You don't have to count them.

If you have access to C++11, `std::array` solves the first two issues,
and should definitely be used in preference to C style arrays in the
first case.  It doesn't address the third, however, and having the
compiler dimension the array according to the number of initializers is
still a valid reason to prefer C style arrays.

Comment: C-style array initialization also removes the need to repeat yourself. `int i[] = { 1, 2, 3 };` continues working with `int i[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };`. `array<int, 3>` needs to be manually changed to `array<int, 4>`.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig A change which you can easily forget.  If you add an element, the compiler should complain, but if you remove one, you'll end up with an extra, 0 initialized element at the end.  I still use C style arrays extensively for this sort of static data.

Comment: The first sentence doesn’t make sense.

Comment: The third point can be solved rather elegantly by using a [`make_array` function](https://gist.github.com/2775736), similar to `make_pair` etc. Hat-tip to [@R. Martinho Fernandes](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/3820452#3820452).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Sure it does. Andreas asks “Should arrays be used in C++?”, to which James replies “Definitely, although with `std::array` in C++11, [they should be used] practically only for static data”.

Comment: @Jon I still don’t see it. *Without* `std::array` *before* C++11, they should practically only be used for static data. *With* `std::array` even that use-case isn’t as strong any more.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Fair enough. I was just interpreting what’s written.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Is `make_array` a const expression.  Or does it cause dynamic initialization?

Comment: @James Well you *can* make it a `constexpr`. In fact, let me amend the gist … there you go (and yes, I tested it, this works).

Comment: With clang I had to put `constexpr` after the arrow. Not sure if that's just a compiler artifact though. Edit: Only in clang 2.9. In 3.1 it has to go next to auto

Answer (score 15):

Never say "never", but I'd agree that their role is greatly diminished by true data structures from STL.

I'd also say that encapsulation inside objects should minimize the impact of choices like this.  If the array is a private data member, you can swap it in or out without affecting clients of your class.

Answer (score 11):

I have worked on safety critical systems where you are unable to use dynamic memory allocation. The memory has to always be on the stack. Therefore in this case you would use arrays as the size is fixed at compile time.

Comment: Before C++11 i would have agreed, but `std::array<T>` allocates on the stacks and basically has no overhead on a raw array.

Comment: @111111 - Agreed. But I know of some folks in that industry has not moved to C++11 yet

Comment: I know that is why I didn't downvote you, but I think boost had a version and it is easy to roll your own as well.

Comment: but in safety critical systems, you don't use new compiler features (less tested), and you don't use boost.

Comment: Many safety critical systems are built on OLD compilers that don't even have the newer compiler features because changing toolchains is a slow, expensive process that requires tons of paperwork, testing, and certifications.

Comment: `std::array` requires C++11, and `boost::array` requires Boost, but `template< typename T, std::size_t N > struct array { T arr[ N ]; typedef T arr_t[N]; operator arr_t &(){ return arr; } operator arr_t const &() const { return arr; } };` is a lot of future proofing in just 7 lines.

Comment: I am flattered that you looked up my past posts.  But using templates muddies the waters sometimes if not careful.

Answer (score 6):

`array` in `c++` gives you fixed size fast alternative of dynamic sized `std::vector` and `std::list`. [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is one of the additions in `c++11`. It provides the benefit of std containers while still providing the aggregate type semantics of C-style arrays.

So in `c++11` i'd certainly use `std::array`, where it is required, over vector. But i'd avoid C style array in `C++03`.

Answer (score 4):

Most usually, **no**, I can't think of a reason to use raw arrays over, say, `vectors`. *If the code is new*.

You might have to resort to using arrays if your libraries need to be compatible with code that expects arrays and raw pointers.

Comment: ... but since C++03 a vector "actually has" an array, which you can access by pointer to read or write. So that covers most cases of code that expects pointers to arrays. It's only really when that code allocates or frees the array that you can't use a vector.

Comment: @SteveJessop can you access the internal array?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: `vector.data()` in C++11 or `&vector.front()` previously.

Comment: @Luchian: provided the vector isn't empty, you can take a pointer to an element (and if it is empty, you can pass a null pointer and a length of 0 to any sensibly-written function that accepts the edge case of a zero-sized buffer). Pretty much the sole purpose of the vector contiguity guarantee added in C++03 was to allow vectors to be used as buffers by pointer-oriented code.

Comment: @SteveJessop And the fact that a lot of people thought it was guaranteed anyway, and it was considered preferable to not disappoint them.

Answer (score 4):

I know a lot of people are pointing out std::array for allocating arrays on the stack, and std::vector for the heap. But neither seem to support non-native alignment.  If you're doing any kind of numeric code that you want use SSE or VPX instructions on (thus requiring 128 or 256 byte alignment respectively), C arrays would still seem to be your best bet.

Answer (score 3):

I would say arrays are still useful, if you are storing a small static amount of data why not.

Answer (score 2):

The only advantage of an array (of course wrapped in something that will manage automatically its deallocation when need) over `std::vector` I can think about is that `vector` cannot pass ownership of its data, unless your compiler supports C++11 and move constructors.

Comment: "vector cannot pass ownership of its data" - yes it can, in C++03, using `swap`.

Answer (score 2):

C style arrays are a fundamental data structure, so there will be cases when it is better to use it. For the general case, however, use the more advanced data structures that round off the corners of the underlying data. C++ allows you to do some very interesting and useful things with memory, many of which work with simple arrays.

Comment: How are C-style arrays more fundamental than `std::array`s? Both will in many cases be compiled to the same assembly.

Comment: More fundamental in that it is more basic. You know what an array is going to do, std::array may have implementation quirks since it relies on the standard library.

Comment: @JamesWynn Not really. `std::array` has precisely defined semantics built on top of static arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You should use STL containers internally, but you should not pass pointers to such containers between different modules, or you will end up in dependency hell. Example:

```
std::string foo;
//  fill foo with stuff
myExternalOutputProc(foo.c_str());
```

is a very good solution but not

```
std::string foo;
//  fill foo with stuff
myExternalOutputProc(&foo);
```

The reason is that std::string can be implemented in many different ways but a c-style string is always a c-style string.

Comment: I think what you are trying to say is: Don't link different object code together if different compilers / implementations of the standard library were used to create them. That's certainly true. How does this relate to the original question?

Comment: It is just an advice *when* to use arrays or STL containers. Build data using a container, pass it as an array. For other data that strings you would have something like myExternalOutputProc(foo.rawPointerGet(),foo.count());

Comment: But these problems only arise when you combine different implementations of the standard library in the same project. That's crazy. In any normal piece of code, it is perfectly ok to pass, say, a vector, by reference (or, in C++11, move it) to a function.

Comment: I just happen to like plug-ins