# how to create a char array in c++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a pointer to a char and pass it to function as a char*.
here is my code to define the char array
it seems the compiler does not recognize the end of the string 
because the function display does not show a correct string

```
char myword[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' }; 
char  str[] = {'M','i','k','e',' ','s','m','i','t','h','\0'};
char str2[] = "Dragic\0";
char* pname=&str[0];
char* pteam=&str2[0];
Display(myword);
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`). **Use the debugger** (`gdb`) and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) if available. Learn about `new`.

Comment: And since you don't show the code of `Display` your question is meaningless.

Comment: How is your Display function defined?

Comment: Please show the definition of `Display`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error inside your `Display()` function. Code you posted is perfectly valid. You can check it [here](http://ideone.com/ms6qZN).

Anyway, why do you declare these arrays this way? You can simply do:

```
char myword[] = "Hello";
char str[] = "Mike Smith";
char str2[] = "Dragic";

char* pname = &str[0];
char* pteam = &str2[0];
```

In case of constant string literals, null terminator is appended automatically. Then:

```
printf("%s\n", myword);
printf("%s\n", str);
printf("%s\n", str2);
printf("%s\n", pname);
printf("%s\n", pteam);
```

Output:

```
Hello
Mike Smith
Dragic
Mike Smith
Dragic
```

You can find working sample [here](http://ideone.com/QqVbdy).

Answer (score -1):

Do not use char arrays if you just need a string, use [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/). If you need an array, use [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/) or [std::array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718061/should-arrays-be-used-in-c)

If you really really have to use naked arrays(heap allocated) and pointers, at least encapsulate it with [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

Comment: In case of fixed arrays, created as objects on local stack I see no point in using `RAII`. There is nothing here, that can lead to memory leak of any kind.