# declare fixed size character array on stack c++

Tags: c++, memory-management, stack

I am attempting to create a character array of a fixed size on the stack (it does need to be stack allocated).  the problem I am having is I cannot get the stack to allocate more than 8 bytes to the array:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
        char* str = new char[50];
        cout << sizeof(str) << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

prints

```
8
```

How do I allocate a fixed size array (in this case 50 bytes. but it may be any number) on the stack?

Comment: `new` does the opposite of allocating on the stack. What you need is a plain, ordinary array. `char str[50];` will do you fine. If you've got C++11, `std::array<char, 50> str;` would be better.

Comment: I'd check exactly what it was `sizeof()` was measuring~ It is not what you think it is.

Comment: Here's some additional information for you. This is a link explaining how sizeOf works: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s7x1k91(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
char* str = new char[50];
cout << sizeof(str) << endl;
```

It prints the size of the pointer, which is `8` on your platform. It is same as these:

```
cout << sizeof(void*) << endl;
cout << sizeof(char*) << endl;
cout << sizeof(int*) << endl;
cout << sizeof(Xyz*) << endl;  //struct Xyz{};
```

All of these would print `8` on your platform.

What you need is one of these:

```
//if you need fixed size char-array; size is known at compile-time.
std::array<char, 50> arr; 

//if you need fixed or variable size char array; size is known at runtime.
std::vector<char> arr(N); 

//if you need string
std::string s;
```

Answer (score 8):

Actually, you are allocating `50 * sizeof(char)`, or 50 bytes. `sizeof(str)` is `sizeof(char*)` which is the size of a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

To put a C array on the stack, you must write

```
char myArray[50] = {0};
```

The C++ way to do this would be - as Nawaz noted

```
std::array<char, 50> arr;
```

But i am not sure if the content of this array will reside on the stack.

Comment: `std::array` is simply a wrapper for C-style, fixed length arrays, so it should be on the stack.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right - although i can not find a valid information about this - modified my post.

Comment: The accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632971/what-is-the-difference-between-stdarray-and-stdvector-when-do-you-use-one-o) has the info.

Answer (score 1):

`str` here is referencing to an array of characters of size `50*sizeof(char)`. But `sizeof(str)` is printing the `sizeof` of `str` variable and not the `sizeof` what it is referencing. `str` here is just a pointer variable and pointer variable is an unsigned integer whose size is `8`.

Also you cannot determine `sizeof` the reference(In this case, the size of character array). This is because the compiler doesn't know what the pointer is pointing to.

**Edit**: Getting the `sizeof` of what the pointer is pointing to doesn't make much sense in C/C++. Suppose a pointer is pointing to a primitive type (like `int`, `long`), then you could directly do `sizeof(int)`. And if the pointer is pointing to an array, like in this case, you could directly do `arraySize * sizeof(dataTypeOfArray)`. `arraySize` is anyways known since C/C++ doesn't allow to define arrays of unknown size, and `dataTypeOfArray` is anyways known.