# Vector of a Vector troubles

Tags: c++, vector, int

***Basic Problem*** Can you please help me understand how to use a vector of a vector. Take for example `vector< vector<int> > help`. I do not understand if it is a vector of ints who each are a vector of ints or if it is a vector of a vector of ints? I also don't understand how to utilize it.

***Example Code***

```
vector< vector<int> > test[500];
test[0].emplace_back(1);
cout << test[0][0];
test[50].emplace_back(4);
cout << " " <<test[50][0];

-console-
1 50 //this is not what happens btw, but it is the desired results
```

***Disclaimer*** I have spent the better part of a morning testing and googling this. Please help :) I did my hw. I can't find any documentation of vectors of a vector. Also I have all the correct libraries and I am using namespace std. I am a noob and i understand that namespaces are bad practice, but its very convient for me right now.

Basically what I want is a set size of a vector filled with each pt being a vector of int. I would rather not go the way of a separate class. Is a vector of a vector of int, the right thing to be looking into?

Thank you :)

Comment: You don't have a vector of vectors. You have an array of vectors of vectors.

Comment: You have an array that contains 500 vector of vectors.

Comment: so if i did vector<int> test[500]; I would have an array that contains 500 vectors of int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a vector of int:

```
std::vector<int> v;
```

this is a vector of vectors of int:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v2;
```

this is an array of vectors of vectors of ints, which is what you have:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> test[500];
```

each element of that array is an `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`. So `test[0]` is one of those.

If you want a vector of 500 default constructed vectors of int, you need

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> test(500);
```

Comment: now googling difference between an array and a vector. Awesome thank you.

Comment: for future reference, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632971/what-is-the-difference-between-stdarray-and-stdvector-when-do-you-use-one-o

Comment: i can't vote u up cuz i no have rep, I would otherwize thank you u for your speedy and concise response

Answer (score 2):

`test` is an array of 500 vectors of vectors of int.  The second line of your example should not even compile here, as you are calling `std::vector< std::vector<int> >::emplace_back()`, which expects an argument compatible with `std::vector<int>`, and you have provided an int.  To clarify:

- `test` is a `std::vector< std::vector<int> >[500]`.
- `test[0]` is a `std::vector< std::vector<int> >`.
- `test[0][0]` is a `std::vector<int>`.
- `test[0][0][0]` is an `int`.

(Pedantic C++ developers will note that the latter three are actually references, but I'm omitting that from the type for clarity.)

Answer (score 2):

A `vector` is just a resizable array.

To declare a vector of `int` (an array of int), just do:

`std::vector<int> vec;`

To declare a array in which individual elements are vectors, you do:

`std::vector< std::vector<int> > vecarr;`

To set the initial size of the vector, you do:

`std::vector<int> vec(500);` not `std::vector<int> vec[500]`, because this creates an array of 500 `std::vectors`. Similarly, `std::vector< std::vector<int> > vec[500];` creates a array of 500 vector of vectors.

To skip writing `std::` you can say `using namespace std` before all this to tell that you're using the `std` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is an array of `vector`-of-`vector` which I believe since you're accessing the data with two indexes is not what you wanted.

I believe you may have just typo-ed your constructor initialization:

```
vector< vector<int> > test(500);   // Note () instead of [] here.
```

This creates a vector-of-vectors, with 500 inner vectors pre-created for you. Then the rest of your code should just work!