# Are there any advantages of C++ Arrays over Vectors?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stl

STL containers are highly efficient and popular, but is there any practical advantage of choosing to use an array instead of an STL container like perhaps, a vector, in any kind of scenario? 
Arrays have several disadvantages, for example, the size information is lost when passing arrays to a function, since it degrades to a pointer. Do vectors or other STL containers also have some disadvantages in some particular situations?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079057/arrays-vs-vectors-introductory-similarities-and-differences

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664272/is-stdvector-so-much-slower-than-plain-arrays

Comment: Everything is a trade off.  The big one with `std::vector` is by default, you are doing dynamic memory allocations.  Do note there is now `std::array` to replace raw arrays

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632971/what-is-the-difference-between-stdarray-and-stdvector-when-do-you-use-one-o (even though that's not exactly what you're asking)

Comment: To clarify, when you say 'Array', do you mean `int arr[3] = {1, 2, 3};`, or `std::array<int, 3> arr = {1, 2, 3};`? Because in C++, when we say 'array', it's usually better to refer to the latter, and uses to the former are discouraged.

Comment: Oh, yeah the link solves my doubt. So should I delete the question as it is a duplicate?

Comment: @Xirema given that "array" is presented here in contrast to "STL containers", I assume it's the former.

Comment: @50calrevolver No need to delete it, it's been marked as duplicate.

Comment: I meant the former one, i.e. int arr[3] = {1, 2, 3}. Actually I am implementing some algorithms for a friend's project and I was thinking that whether I should change all the pre-written code so that vectors are used instead of arrays. Now I am convinced to go with STL

Comment: *"the size information is lost when passing arrays to a function"* - Not necessarily. You *can* pass arrays by reference, which then retains the size information.